# Numbers from Google sheet document are different after importing to R

Tags: r, google-sheets, format

I have a table in Google sheet which I have imported to R with the help of Google sheet package. Number in google sheet table are correct but once I have imported them to R, they have a different structure.

For example, I am analyzing the performance of players and I have data for the minute duration during the game like 93 ( which is that the player 93 minutes). But the data in R are showed like this 9.302000e+01.

Some numbers are correct some are in the format below. I am really struggling to figure it out what can be the problem. I have checked the format in sheets as well as in excel and it is as numeric.

As said, I have a number like in table like 93, 22, 93, 16, 45, 93, 46, 93 ( minutes played)

But in R they are some incorrect and some correct.

for example

93.0000000  2.200000e+01    93.0200000  1.600000e+01    4.500000e+01    93.0200000  46.0000000  9.302000e+01

```
install.packages("googlesheets")
library(googlesheets)

gs_auth(new_user = TRUE)

be <- gs_title("zilina_player_overview")
```

My expected result is, of course, to have a table in the format like I have it in google sheets or excel. I mean when a player played 93 minutes I will see there number 93 and not 9.302000e+01.

Any help is welcome, and thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Please format the cells in google sheets to see 3 decimal digits after the point.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for quick response. Do you mean like this please 93.000 22.000 93.020 16.000 45.000 93.020 46.000 93.020 70.000 93.000 76.000 93.000 93.000?

Comment: yes. Is this your result in google sheets after the formatting?

Comment: Second please, this is from google sheets, am going to test it in R. Really thank you

Comment: Sadly, still the same result. Will try again, but still thank you a lot for advice

Comment: Can you share a copy of an example sheet to see if others can reproduce the issue?

Comment: The number `93.02` is rounded to `93` if it is displayed without digits after the decimal point.

Comment: hello, sorry for later response.can i put the link to google sheets here? is that allowed?

Comment: This is the link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P-_qbSyMzMBR9H_co80l2wFGE5qU9UEIhPAxPT0atlg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Nice day wishing, i tried to format the numbers in the sheet but for some reason the problem in R persist. Any advice please? Thank you very much